# PHP Debugger will not stop at breakpoints: Eclipse & Xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, breakpoints

---

**Client Side Tools:** ( No Apache, No PHP )

---

**Eclipse for PHP Developers**

Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

Build id: 20171218-0600

**Redhat Enterprise Linux 6.9**

**java version "1.8.0_101"**

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

---

**Remote Server Where The PHP web app is:**

---

**PHP 5.6.5**

**Zend Engine v2.6.0**, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

with **Xdebug v2.2.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans**

---

I've found previous posts on this topic.  I didn't understand all of the things to try.  I tried what I could understand, but did not have any luck. Mostly just using xdebug_break(); ( again, no luck )

---

I am using Eclipse and Xdebug to debug a remote PHP web site.  My problem is I can not get the debugger to stop on the breakpoints I set.

I am doing remote PHP development with Eclipse and a "Synchronized PHP Project.  Nothing except Eclipse is running on my computer.

I am using the Xdebug debugger on the remote server through Eclipse.

When I use the debugger it will go to the index.php.  I can step through for a while and see the value of variables.

The problem is that Xdebug will not stop at any of the breakpoints I set.

I am including my Xdebug settings

Any clues as to how to find and fix the problem would be welcome

**Xdebug Settings:**

```
xdebug support,enabled
Version,2.2.7

DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol,$Revision: 1.145 $

Directive,Local Value,Master Value

xdebug.auto_trace,Off,Off
xdebug.cli_color,0,0
xdebug.collect_assignments,Off,Off

xdebug.collect_includes,On,On

xdebug.collect_params,0,0
xdebug.collect_return,Off,Off
xdebug.collect_vars,Off,Off

xdebug.coverage_enable,On,On
xdebug.default_enable,On,On

xdebug.dump.COOKIE,no value,no value
xdebug.dump.ENV,no value,no value
xdebug.dump.FILES,no value,no value
xdebug.dump.GET,no value,no value
xdebug.dump.POST,no value,no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST,no value,no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER,no value,no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION,no value,no value

xdebug.dump_globals,On,On
xdebug.dump_once,On,On

xdebug.dump_undefined,Off,Off

xdebug.extended_info,On,On

xdebug.file_link_format,no value,no value

xdebug.max_nesting_level,100,100
xdebug.overload_var_dump,On,On

xdebug.profiler_aggregate,Off,Off
xdebug.profiler_append,Off,Off
xdebug.profiler_enable,Off,Off

xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger,On,On
xdebug.profiler_output_dir,/tmp,/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name,cachegrind.out.%t.%s,cachegrind.out.%t.%s

xdebug.remote_autostart,Off,Off

xdebug.remote_connect_back,On,On
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time,3600,3600
xdebug.remote_enable,On,On
xdebug.remote_handler,dbgp,dbgp
xdebug.remote_host,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log,/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log,/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode,req,req
xdebug.remote_port,9000,9000

xdebug.scream,Off,Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace,Off,Off
xdebug.show_local_vars,Off,Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta,Off,Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger,Off,Off

xdebug.trace_format,0,0
xdebug.trace_options,0,0
xdebug.trace_output_dir,/tmp,/tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name,trace.%c,trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children,128,128
xdebug.var_display_max_data,512,512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth,3,3
```

**Edit**

I created an album of screen shots.

First one is an error message from Eclipse that happens when I leave it on all night.

The rest of the screen shots are pieces, in order ( top->down ) of my phpinfo output.

https://imgur.com/a/9DKev

There is no Zend section in my phpinfo() output, though there are these vars

```
report_zend_debug = on
zend.detect_unicode On
zend.enable_gc  On
zend.multibyte  Off 
zend.script_encoding = no value
```

Comment: @kerbholz think that was a problem with the title as later it does say it doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Comment: @Steve, though the article I wrote was for docker, but same things apply on normal server also. Have a look http://tarunlalwani.com/post/debugging-php-xdebug-docker/

Answer (score 7):

From your description, it seems that:

- the debug connection to your remote server is working
- breaking points work on the index.php, but not anywhere else

My assumption is that the **file mapping** between local and server code is not working, more precisely eclipse cannot map your files to the server ones.

To solve this, you have to set the **path mapping** setting inside your eclipse project `s **run/debug settings**.

Go to:

1. Project -> Properties from the menu
2. Select Run/Debug Settings
3. Edit your **launch configuration settings**
4. On the tab Server, section **PHP server**, select **configure**
5. "PHP Server" window is opened, select **path mapping** tab
6. Set **Path on server** to your project `s path on server and set **Local path** to well this is self explanatory.

[image]

Comment: I've had that set from the beginning.  I tried the local path both the "path" option and the "path from workspace" option.  No dice either way.

Comment: Can you post the paths set and also a path to a php file that the breakpoints do not work?

Comment: Path on server:

/home/jsmith/public_html/xyz

Comment: Local path
/export/abc/jsmith/Projects/XYZ/Workspace/xyzdev_remote

Comment: Path to a PHP file where breakpoints do not work:
/export/abc/jsmith/Projects/XYZ/Workspace/xyzdev_remote/lib/xyz/db_classes/display.php

Comment: Are you using an nfs mount on your local pc for your project pointing to the server project folder?

Comment: No. My local PC and the server are completely unconnected.  I have a copy of the project files on my local PC in my Eclipse workspace.

Comment: The /export/abc/jsmith is my home directory on my local PC

Comment: Is it by any chance an nfs mount to a vagrant, docker or virtualbox? Can you run "stat -f -L -c %T /export/abc/jsmith" from the command line?

Comment: That was easy, one single word of output: nfs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165298/discussion-between-jannes-botis-and-steve).

Comment: This was my problem exactly some time ago using PHPStorm

Comment: For people on Windows having the same problem "php-debugger-will-not-stop-at-breakpoints-eclipse-xdebug", check XDebug is correctly installed and configured. For instructions, go to https://xdebug.org/wizard.

Comment: ... and do not forget to update the [xdebug] section in php.ini. Typically you have to set xdebug.remote_enable = on

Answer (score 4):

If you follow below steps I think it should work

**Latest XDebug version**

Your XDebug version is from 2015 as per this https://xdebug.org/. So you should upgrade to the latest version

**Setting up XDebug configuration**

Setup a `99-xdebug.ini` in your `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/` or `/etc/php/conf.d` or `/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d` depending on which exists on your system

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

**Create a SSH Debug Tunnel**

The machine from where you want to debug, you need to start a SSH tunnel using

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:9000:127.0.0.1:9000 -p 22 <user>@<phpserver>
```

**Configure Remote Path mapping in Eclipse**

Configure eclipse for the debugging on port 9000 and remote paths and now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable things like: opcache, zend optimizer, and so on, all extensions what work with interpretation php code. If you luck and it start working, make xdebug.so loads last, after all another modules, so you can re enable them again. Place xdebug.so in folder where all other php .so resides, and load it in last line of php ini, with *full path* to xdebug.so

If you just place it in last line php.ini, then some incompatible module can load up after, with config from /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/*. So just move configs somewhere for a while.

At the link, in bottom of post, I do disable(*but do not remove by apt*) opchache module totally, and place its in php.ini, 1 line before debugger.

Check order how extensions loaded in phpinfo() output, to the left of zend logo, as I remember. Debugger must be last line in that block of output. Post you phpinfo(); output.

Another way, what I walk my own: (and I recommend it)

If you have root access to remote server, try Zend Debugger. Its bundled with Zend Studio(not free), *but* there are separate downloads of debugger for some php versions, 5.6 is the latest version it available for. They don`t publish it for php7, anyway I don`t known if it possible to copy it from trial Zend studio. If it removed, unable to download, I can send it to you.

Zend debugger are more native for php now, And Zend team involved in Eclipse PDT development(but they realized most tasteful features in paid version)

I have similar environment to yours, also have problems with XDebug, then decided to remove it and try Zend debugger. There are my question and answer on askubuntu, about installing it and fix problems: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002252/installing-configuring-zend-debugger-for-eclipse-pdt

In few words solution was:

> Comment out it in config: (cli version seems to be symlink as also disabled)

`lenya@JabbaDesktop:~$ sudo nano /etc/php/5.6/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini`

```
; configuration for php opcache module
; priority=10
; zend_extension=opcache.so
```

> At bottom of /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20131226/opcache.so"
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/20131226/ZendDebugger.so"
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.0/8,192.168.0.0/16
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=1
zend_debugger.connector_port=10137
```

> First two lines(.so) should be exactly in this order.
>   *Installing debugger "how to" easy to find in google. No one mention above problem.*

**Update:**

> When I use the debugger it will go to the index.php. I can step through for a while and see the value of variables.

This means you already have connection to server, problem is not there

Comment: Also one thing to mention, I didn`t install something with pecl, all done manually, this way you known what happens.

Comment: Most "paid" features from Zend Studio are in PDT since 5.0 (PHPUnit, Validation, Profiling, Synchronized Project) ;)

Comment: Yes, thats good, but I need more, more :) Graphical DB design integrated to Eclipse, and code hinting for ExtJS and JQuery and more :) Is it possible to cut plugins from trial version?

Comment: Try dbeaver, available on marketplace. It support many dbs. Zend studio used old JSDT for js, current version doesn’t work well so I cannot refommend alternative for now.

Comment: I created an album of screen shots.

First one is an error message from Eclipse that happens when I leave it on all night.

The rest of the screen shots are pieces, in order ( top->down ) of my phpinfo output.

https://imgur.com/a/9DKev

Comment: Tried googling on Opache, got other things, what does it do?
Using Zend debugger isn't an option for me.
I don't have root access, but I can get someone to disable things for me, but I can't go to the well too often with asking him to turn things on and off several times.

Comment: There is no Zend section in my phpinfo() output, though there are these vars

report_zend_debug = on
zend.detect_unicode On
zend.enable_gc On
zend.multibyte Off 
zend.script_encoding = no value

Comment: @Steve Error message says what your xdebug is wrong version, you should install correct version exactly. Or try Zend debugger :) There are Zend engine section on second screen, there opcache and xdebug seen. Try to disable opcache for a while, but first do correct xdebug version.

Comment: @Steve, I just read all your comments, so you don't have root access but have system administrator :) Tell him version of xdebug is incompatible with php version, so install correct version. Not the latest version but version exactly compatible. You have connection, as able to see variables when stepping, try without ssh yet  as it not working, but later you should encrypt traffic.

Comment: @LeonidMew  Thanks, I just sent the sysadmin an email telling him we need Xdebug 2.5.5 for PHP 5.6.5

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing remote PHP development with Eclipse and a "Synchronized PHP Project. Nothing except Eclipse is running on my computer.

This is your problem. You have to allow xDebug connection.  xDebug (PHP Web Server) trying to connect but probably have no idea where you are ;)

There two options:

1. If you are not behind NAT or in same network as your test server, you have to open port 9000 on your PC. If you are behind NAT you need also forward port 9000 (this is default, can be changed). Next set correct `"xdebug.remote_host=your_public_ip"` or `xdebug.remote_connect_back = on`. Would be also good to enable accepting remote sessions (JIT) from any host (Preferences -> PHP -> Debug -> Debuggers -> xDebug), after this you will be able to easy run debugger via browser extension like xDebug helper.
2. Configure debugger launch configuration (small arrow after "debug" icon"), to debug through SSH Tunnel. In this case `xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1` will be correct. *Note: ssh server host have to be same as server domain and SSH server have to be available on port 22*

Comment: What is a NAT and how would I tell if I am behind one?

Comment: Full definition you can find on wiki, in short your public IP address (visible on internet) is different to IP assigned to your network card (cable or WIFI). Often your local IP is 192.162.0-255.2-255. Public ip (how you are visible on network) you can find here: http://whatismyip.com/ , private IP you can find in windows/linux/mac network preferences.

Comment: My public IP is 140.90.100.199.  Via ifconfig my inet addrr is 10.90.195.104. My Local loopback inet addr is 127.0.0.1.

How do I know if my 9000 port is open or closed?

My xdebug.remote_connect_back = on

I need to leave xdebug.remote_host = xdebug.remote_host,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1

Comment: https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ Use  public address and port 9000. Eclipse have to be opened. If connect_back is enabled, remote_host is ignored.

Comment: I tried doing an SSH Tunnel in my debug configuration.  When I hit the "Test Connection" button I got "Connected with warnings", and the warning was "the debugger tunnel might not have been initialized.  Then I got a blank gray window coming up.

Comment: zulus, yes I have xdebug.remote_connect_back enabled.  I can't have xdebug on the server set up for just one IP address as people from multiple sites will want to remote debug.

Comment: I created an album of screen shots.

First one is an error message from Eclipse that happens when I leave it on all night.

The rest of the screen shots are pieces, in order ( top->down ) of my phpinfo output.

https://imgur.com/a/9DKev

Comment: There is no Zend section in my phpinfo() output, though there are these vars

report_zend_debug = on
zend.detect_unicode On
zend.enable_gc On
zend.multibyte Off 
zend.script_encoding = no value

Comment: This popup is from Zend Debugger, but you trying to run xDebug. Make sure your weblaunch configuration on "Debugger" tab "xDebug" is visible.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse has been set at xDebug i that and other spots.  I checked the Xdebug site and the version we have is slightly under for the PHP version, so perhaps it isn't a Zend debugger messsage since we don't have that, but the Zend framework asking for a higher version of Xdebug

Comment: I'll prepare test remote machine and let you know. Maybe there is a bug on PDT or even xDebug 2.2.7. BTW did you set correctly path mapping on Eclipse PHP Server configuration ?